# What is meant by Octet String? What's the difference between Octet and Char?

Tags: c

What is the difference between octet string and char? How can an octet string be used? Can anybody write a small C program on Octet string? How are octet strings stored in memory?

Comment: Sorry, only those who have taken lessons playing the Octet can write programs on Octet string. ;-)  They are stored in memory along with other variables.  I would only worry about Octets when the one of the other musicians doesn't show. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Standards (and such) use "octet" to explicitly state that they're talking about 8-bit groups. While most current computers work with bytes that are also 8 bits in size, that's not necessarily the case. In fact, "byte" is rather poorly defined, with considerable disagreement over what it means for sure -- so it's generally avoided when precision is needed.

Nonetheless, on a typical computer, an octet is going to be the same thing as a byte, and an octet stream will be stored in a series of bytes.

Comment: Now if a byte is not standard, how can we trust file sizes?

Comment: @user13947194: For the most part you can *now*. Once upon a time, file sizes on some systems were pretty strange though For example, Control Data used to measure file sizes in "system resource units" (SRU's), each of which was (going from distant memories here) around 600 characters (of 6 bits apiece).

Comment: For such a 6 bits a piece system; was memory also bits a piece or was memory addressabe in 8 bit units?

Comment: @user13947194: On that machine, memory was addressable in 60-bit words (and when storing strings, each word could contain 10 characters). For some others (e.g., the PDP-10) the situation gets more complex.

Answer (score 1):

- An octet is another word for a 8-bit byte.
- A char is usually 8 bits, but may be another size on some architectures.

Comment: signed char (signed being optional on most compilers, a changeable behavior) in ANSI C is not less than 8bits, not more than 8bits, and 8bits exactely. It's decimal representation, after 2-complements conversion, goes from -127 to 128. unsigned char goes from 0 to 255.

Comment: @jpinto3912: it goes _at least_ from -127 to 127 or from 0 to 255, but it can cover a wider range. In fact, signed chars usually cover a wider range, from -128 to 127.

Comment: @jp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: @ninjalj, thanks for pointing that, my bad... it was a speed-typo, I did meant -128 to 127, as in what you get from 2-complements on 8-bits. But you raised a very interesting and valid point: "at least -127", which is what you would get on a 1-complements storing computer.

Comment: @Kenny, Ansi C has a default of char=8bits... apparently this can be changed (haven't checked, and wonder what mental conditions would trigger someone to change that). So char can (sic) be more than 8 bits. I eat my hat.

Comment: @jp: All I know is ISO C requires `CHAR_BIT ≥ 8`. I don't know how it is in ANSI C.

Comment: @jpinto3912: The mental conditions nowadays typically involve writing/porting a C compiler for a 16-bit or 32-bit DSP. Also, ISO C supports 2-complement, 1-complement and sign-magnitude representations for integers.

Comment: @ninjalj, I think it's a bit mental to have the compiler treat char as more than 8bits, when we have int to play with. It's well understood that DSP/CPU memory word or instruction operands length might imply using 8bit var/const is less fast than using 16 or 32bit... but the compiler can make those padding/alignment changes as speed optimizations (i.e. use a whole 16/32bit mem-position and trunc at 8).

Comment: You can (or, more likely, could once upon a time) have 9-bit `char` on machines with 36-bit word size.  There were also other words lengths that were not a multiple of 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

An octet is 8 bits meant to be handled together (hence the "oct" in "octet").  It's what we think of when we say "byte" these days.

A char is basically a byte -- it's defined as the smallest addressable unit of memory, which on almost all modern computers is the same as an octet.  But there have been computers with 9-bit, 16-bit, even 36-bit "words" that qualify as chars by that definition.  You only need to care about those computers (and thus, about the difference between a char and an octet) if you have one -- let the people who have the weird hardware worry about how to make their programs run on it.

Comment: This doesn't only happen in ancient PDP's. Some DSP's from TI have 16 or 32-bit chars,

Answer (score 0):

An octet string is simply a sequence of bits grouped into chunks of 8.  Those 8-sized groups often represent characters.  Octet string is a basic data type used for SNMP.

Answer (score -1):

A string used to be a set of octets, which is turn is a set of 8 bits.

A string in C, is always a null-terminated, memory contiguous, set of bytes.
Back in the day, each byte, an octet, represented a character. That's why they named the type used to make strings, **char**.

The ASCII table, that goes from 0 to 127, with the graphics/accents version going from 0 to 255, was no longer enough for displaying characters in a string, so someone though of adding bits to a character representation. Dumb-asses from CS though of 9bit and so forth, to what HW guys replied "are you nuts??? keep it a multiple of memory addressing unit", which was the byte, back then.
Enter wide-character strings, i.e. 16bits per character.
On a WC string, each character is represented by 2 bytes... there goes your char=1 byte rule down the drain.

To keep an exact description of a string, if it's a set of characters-represented-by-8bits (in Earth, following the ASCII table, but I've been to Mars), it's an "octet string".

If it's not "octet string" it may or may not be WC... Joel was a [nice post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on this.

Comment: An octet is an 8-bit byte. It is in contrast to other byte sizes that sometimes surfaced, like the 6-bit, 9-bit or 12-bit bytes on old hardware like PDP's.