# C bit array macros, could anyone explain me how these work?

Tags: c, macros, bitarray

I'm trying to implement sieve of erathostenes for school project and I've decided to do so using bit arrays. While I was searching for materials, I came across these 3 macros, they work flawlessly, but I can't really read(understand) them.

```
#define ISBITSET(x,i) ((x[i>>3] & (1<<(i&7)))!=0)
#define SETBIT(x,i) x[i>>3]|=(1<<(i&7));
#define CLEARBIT(x,i) x[i>>3]&=(1<<(i&7))^0xFF;
```

Could you please explain to me at least one of them in detail, I have very basic knowledge about bitwise operations in C (basically I know they "exist").

Will this work on another architecture using different endianness?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, those macros assume evilly that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, and `i >> 3` is actually `i / 8`. (So really this code should say `i / CHAR_BIT`.) This first expression computes the *byte* which contains your desired bit, and is thus the array index in your array `x` (which should be an array of `unsigned char`!).

Now that we've selected the correct byte, namely `x[i >> 3]` (or `x[i / CHAR_BIT]` in your own, better code), we have to do the bit-fiddling. Again, `i & 7` really wants to be `i % CHAR_BIT`, and it extracts only the remainder of your bit count that gives you the offset *within* the byte.

**Example.** Requesting the 44th bit with `i = 43`, and assuming `CHAR_BIT = 8`, `i / CHAR_BIT` is 5, so we're in the sixth byte, and `i % CHAR_BIT` is 3, so we're looking at the fourth bit of the sixth byte.

The actual bit-fiddling itself does the usual stuff; e.g. testing for a given bit performs bit-wise AND with the appropriate bit pattern (namely `1 << k` for the `k`th bit); setting the bit uses bit-wise OR, and zeroing it requires something a tiny bit more involved (think about it!).

Comment: It will work for `CHAR_BIT>8` (but not use all bits), and even if `CHAR_BIT<8`, `x` can be `int[]`

Comment: @asaelr: Well, depends on the specification, I suppose, whether you want a tight bitfield or just "some bits somewhere". For a tight bitfield, `x` essentially has to be an array of `unsigned char`s; or we should modify it to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x)` for the general case.

Comment: @asaelr so when I use f.e. 4B integer (int32_t), it will use just first byte of each integer? That does not seem right, I wanna do something like int32_t *sieve= malloc( (max_index % 32 == 0 ? max_index/32 : max_index/32 +1) * sizeof(int32_t));
Working with chars will make it simplier, but I guess it does not matter much.

Comment: @AoeAoe: Indeed, you will only use the first byte with my code, and only the first eight bit with your code, of each array element. Multiply by `sizeof(x)` to use the entire element. (`sizeof` returns the size in bytes.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess you meant `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(*x)`. @AoeAoe your code access the first 8 bits of every element. if the element is not `char`, and you want to access all its bits, use `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(*x)`. BTW, you can write just `(max_index+31)/32`, and `sizeof(int32_t)` is always 4.

Comment: Thank you all for valueable comments, I mark this one as "solving" and will upvate asaelr's answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

`x`is array of chars. `i` is an index of bits. since every `char` is 8 bits, the last 3 bits of `i` define the bit in the char, and the rest bits define the char in the array.

`i>>3` shift i 3 bits to the right, so you get the part that tell you which char, so `x[i>>3]` is the char that contain the bit indexed by`i`.

`i&7` is the last 3 bits of `i` (since `710==1112`), so it's the index of the bit in the char. `1<<(i&7)` is a char (truly it's int, but in this context you can ignore the difference), that has the bit indexed by `i` on, and the rest bits off. (the mask of the bit)

`char&mask` is the common way to check if bit is on.

`char|=mask` is the common way to turn bit in.

`char&=~mask` is the common way to turn bit off, and if `mask` is char, then `~mask==mask^0xFF`.

I don't think that these macros are endiannes-depend. (if you got `x` by converting `int[]` to `*char`, it's a different story)

Answer (score -1):

```
#define ISBITSET(x,i) (((x)[(i) / CHAR_BIT] & (1u << ((i) % CHAR_BIT))) != 0)
#define SETBIT(x,i) (x)[(i) / CHAR_BIT] |= (1u << ((i) % CHAR_BIT);
#define CLEARBIT(x,i) (x)[(i) / CHAR_BIT] &= ~(1u << ((i) % CHAR_BIT))
```

- Always put parenthesis around macro arguments
- always prefer unsigned types for bit operations
- (1u << CHAR_BIT) is 256 for 8 bit platforms
- there was an exra `;` after the last macro

Comment: How does this explain *at least one of them in detail* ?

Comment: I don't intend to do the work of the teacher. I just wanted to point out the trivial errors that are present in this exercise.

Comment: I was merely remarking your answer is useful but doesn't *answer* the question.

Comment: I don't care about downvotes. I just don't like doing *wrong* homework exercises for lazy people. I probably spent more time on the *wrong* answer than the OP did on his cut&paste job.