# Character size in Java vs. C

Tags: java, c, jvm, character

Why does a character in Java take twice as much space to store as a character in C?

Comment: Java is twice as powerful as C++, and the power has to come from somewhere...

Comment: @KerrekSB But it can have 256x as many characters. ;)

Answer (score 27):

In Java characters are 16-bit and C they are 8-bit.

A more general question is why is this so?

To find out why you need to look at **history** and come to conclusions/**opinions** on the subject.

When C was developed in the USA, ASCII was pretty standard there and you only really needed 7-bits, but with 8 you could handle some non-ASCII characters as well.  It might seem more than enough.  Many text based protocols like SMTP (email), XML and FIX, still only use ASCII character.  Email and XML encode non ASCII characters. Binary files, sockets and stream are still only 8-bit byte native.

BTW: C can support wider characters, but that is not plain `char`

When Java was developed 16-bit seemed like enough to support most languages.  Since then unicode has been extended to characters above 65535 and Java has had to add support for codepoints which is UTF-16 characters and can be one or two 16-bit characters.

So making a `byte` a byte and `char` an unsigned 16-bit value made sense at the time.

BTW: If your JVM supports `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` it can use bytes instead of chars for Strings which only use 8-bit characters.

Comment: Well now that is more like it :) +1

Comment: To be precise, in C they are *at least* 8-bit.

Comment: @Zenzen I wanted to get in an answer before someone closed the question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because Java uses Unicode, C generally uses ASCII by default.

There are various flavours of Unicode encoding, but Java uses UTF-16, which uses either one or two 16-bit *code units* per character. ASCII always uses one byte per character.

- http://java.about.com/od/programmingconcepts/a/unicode.htm
- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: UTF-16 does not "use two bytes per char".

Comment: Sorry, "at least" two bytes per character.

Answer (score 1):

> The Java 2 platform uses the [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) representation in char arrays and
>   in the String and StringBuffer classes.

- [java.lang.Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)
- [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 1):

Java is a **modern** language that came up around the *early Unicode era* (in the beginning of the '90s), so it supports Unicode by default as a first class citizen like most new *contemporary* languages (like Python, Visual Basic or JavaScript...), OSes (Windows, Symbian, BREW...) and frameworks/interfaces/specifications... (like Qt, NTFS, Joliet). By the time those were designed, **Unicode was a *fixed* 16-bit charset** encoded in [UCS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2), so it made sense for them to use 16-bit Unicode characters

In contrast C is an "ancient" language that was invented decades before Java, when Unicode was far from a thing. That's the age of 7-bit ASCII and 8-bit EBCDIC, thus C uses 8-bit char<sup>†</sup> as **that's enough for a `char` variable to contain all basic characters**. When coming to the Unicode times, to refrain from breaking old code they introduced a different character type to C90 which is [`wchar_t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C/C++). Again this is the '90s when Unicode began its life. In any cases *`char` must continue to have the old size* because you still need to access individual bytes even if you use wider characters (Java, Python, VB... all have a separate `byte` type for this purpose)

---

Of course later the Unicode Consortium quickly realized that 16 bits are not enough and must fix it somehow. They widened the code-point range by changing UCS-2 to [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) to avoid breaking old code that uses [wide char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) and have Unicode as a 21-bit charset (actually up to [U+10FFFF instead of U+1FFFFF because of UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351/995714)). Unfortunately it was too late and *the old implementations that use **16-bit char** got stuck*

Later we saw the advent of [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which proved to be far superior to UTF-16 because it's independent of endianness, generally takes up less space, and most importantly it **requires no changes in the standard C string functions**. Most user functions that receive a `char*` will continue to work without special Unicode support

Unix systems are lucky because they migrated to Unicode later when UTF-8 had been introduced, therefore continue to use 8-bit `char`. OTOH all modern Win32 APIs work on 16-bit `wchar_t` by default because Windows was also an early adopter of Unicode. As a result .NET framework and C# also go the same way by having char as a 16-bit type.

---

Talking about `wchar_t`, it was so unportable that both C and C++ standards needed to introduce the new character types [`char16_t` and `char32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) in their 2011 revisions

> Both C and C++ introduced fixed-size character types `char16_t` and `char32_t` in the 2011 revisions of their respective standards to provide unambiguous representation of 16-bit and 32-bit Unicode transformation formats, leaving wchar_t implementation-defined
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#Programming_specifics

That said, most implementations are working on improving the wide string situation. Java experimented with [compressed string](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) in Java 6 and introduced [compact strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44178432/995714) in Java 9. Python is moving to a [more flexible internal representation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) compared to `wchar_t*` in Python before 3.3. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Guide/Internal_strings) and [Chrome](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d2/db3/classv8_1_1_string.html) have separate internal 8-bit char representations for simple strings. There are also discussions on that for [.NET framework](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6612), and C#11 supports [UTF-8 string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/utf8-string-literals). And more recently Windows is gradually introducing [UTF-8 support for the old ANSI APIs](https://superuser.com/a/1451686/241386)

---

<sup>†</sup> Strictly speaking `char` in C is only required to have **at least 8 bits**. See [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Java `char` is an UTF-16-encoded Unicode code point while C uses ASCII encoding in most of the cases.

Comment: I thought I would simplify the phrasing but you're right. 'A unicode char' it's just wrong. Edited the reply.