# OOM error while reading 2GB xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, java-8, xml-parsing

I have been trying to read an XML file which is of 2GB. I have followed different methods to read it but each of those methods give `OutOfMemoryError` I even tried to increase heapsize  max to 4GB and min 2GB heap size in eclispe but still problem persists. How can i resolve this problem? I don't want to use any third party libaray.

Following is the code that i have tried so far

```
String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathname)),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(pathname))) {

while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {

    String line = scanner.nextLine();

   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you reading the XML file? What do you want to do with the information? This is critical to finding a solution to the problem. Reading the whole file into a single Java string doesn't seem a good way of starting, regardless what you want to do with it next.

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree with you. I had this task as of my data science project. It was initial requirement by my mentor to store all data in one string. I had to perform specific task on that particular strings then. I ended up using Sax parser then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each character uses at least 2 bytes and you also need memory for processing. I would give it a lot more memory like 24 GB and see how much it really needs.

Note Java 9+ has compressed string which can reduce consumption.

A better approach is to use SAX parser to process the file as you read it which will use a tiny fraction of the memory.

Comment: My machine is of 8GB. I tried 8 as well, nothing happens. I assume then there is no way to go. I'd have to use SAx parser. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what is a bit painful is that even if there is a single letter outside `Latin1` - the entire String uses 2 bytes per char

Comment: Oh wait, that means i can't have whole content of xml into one string.

Comment: The question is if yiu really need to have in memory the whole 2gb, maybe you can read and process directly

Comment: @Eugene Oracle/OpenJDK Java 9+'s Compressed Strings can use a byte[] instead of a char[]. BTW Java 6 used to have the feature but it was dropped in Java 7.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir BTW A String is limited to 2 billion characters (2^31-1)

Comment: BTW 16 GB is around $100 so might be worth the investment.

Comment: @PeterLawrey not can, but will. always. Its just a matter oh how big that byte array is. My point was that because a certain letter is outside Latin1, meaning that that single letter for example needs to be encoded into 2 bytes, it spoils the party for everyone else; even if everyone else needs just one byte.

Comment: @PeterLawrey also [this is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178432/difference-between-compact-strings-and-compressed-strings-in-java-9)

Comment: @Eugenen Thank you for that reference. +1

Comment: @Eugene and that single non-latin character does not only cause the string to consume twice the memory; since it is a byte array in Java 9, needing two bytes per character reduces the maximum string size to the halve of the maximum array size, i.e. less than 2³⁰ characters.