# Why does JProfiler shows me such a big overhead of 200+ bytes per char[] in Java?

Tags: java, scala, oop, memory, jvm

JProfiler shos me 5M char[] instances take 2.5GB. The text itself in those char[] is a total of 1.2GB from a file. The 1.3GB seems overhead from the array instances, their fields like length, any alignment that the JVM might do. But still looks like too much?
On the higher level what I keep in memory is a HashMap.
JProfiler shows me that:

```
5M char[]: 2.5GB
5M String: 126MB
2.6M HashMap$Node: 84MB
```

Please advise, why would the JVM take so much heap overhead for the char[] instances, or perhaps the JProfiler can't do such an accurate reporting on the heap consumption by instances of each class?

Comment: What exactly are you storing in the char[] arrays? What does the distribution of array lengths look like?

Comment: Better still can you give us a MRE?

Comment: @PiRocks 2.5M have 411 chars on average, ascii i would say; the other 2.5M half have 5 chars each

Comment: @PiRocks what is an MRE? A memory snapshot?

Comment: MRE=minimal reproducible example.

Comment: For small arrays keep in mind that arrays need to store some kind of class pointer and a array length value. If both of these are 64 bit that can add a fair bit of overhead.

Comment: And this might be a long shot, but you are aware that chars are two bytes in Java right?

Comment: One final possible explanation that comes to mind is strong internment

Comment: @PiRocks go ahead and give the answer. I had in mind that in UTF8, the ascii chars are represented as 1 byte. Now I store byte[] instead of Strings and i have the memory consumption in half. Yes, the primitive char is two bytes. Good to clarify.

Comment: @NicuMarasoiu _or_ you can upgrade to java-9 or newer, where Strings ( latin1) are stored as `byte[]`.

Comment: As @Eugene said the newer JDKs have "Compact Strings" optimization which should cut down the overhead, at least for ASCII strings (as soon as you have a non-ascii character in your string the overhead jumps back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is because chars in java are unsigned 2 byte values. Therefore if you read an ascii file into a `String` object you should expect roughly a 2x overhead.

As pointed out by @Eugene and @Jurah Martinka, newer VMs have optimizations for this. 
You can see more info on those optimizations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44179353/3424746).

Comment: yea, used Java 11 which can also be used to compile Scala quite well