# Implicit conversion of unsigned char (arithmetic conversion vs. assignment)

Tags: c, casting

In am working on something and came across code similar to the following:

```
#define MODULUS(a,b)        ((a) >= 0 ? (a)%(b) : (b)-(-a)%(b))

unsigned char w;
unsigned char x;
unsigned char y;
char z;

/* Code that assigns values to w,x and y.  All values assigned 
   could have been represented by a signed char. */

z = MODULUS((x - y), w);
```

It is my understanding that the arithmetic `(x - y)` will be accomplished prior to any type conversion and the macro will always evaluate to `(a)%(b)` -- as the result will be an unsigned char which is always greater than or equal to zero.  However, the code functions as intended and I think that my understanding is flawed.  So...

My questions are these:

1. Does an implicit type conversion to signed char occur before the expression is evaluated?
2. Is there a situation (for example, if the unsigned values were large enough that they could not be represented by a signed value) where the above code would not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does an implicit type conversion to signed char occur before the expression is evaluated?

No, a conversion to `int` occurs before the expression `x - y` is evaluated¹. Thus the result can be negative.

> Is there a situation (for example, if the unsigned values were large enough that they could not be represented by a signed value) where the above code would not work?

If `sizeof int == 1`, the integer promotion would promote the `unsigned char`s to `unsigned int`s, and that could produce wrong results because before the modulus by `w`, a modulus by `UINT_MAX + 1` is performed due to unsigned arithmetic.

¹ The default integer promotion.

Comment: C99 (sec 5.2.4.2.1, at least of the n1124 draft), requires `INT_MIN` to be less than or equal to -32767, and `INT_MAX` to be greater than or equal to 32767.  So, at least in C99, `sizeof(int) >= 2`.

Comment: @sfstewman `CHAR_BIT` can be greater than 8. If `CHAR_BIT` is 16 or larger, `sizeof(int)` can be 1. Unlikely, but possible. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char)

Comment: That's fascinating.  Thanks for the link.  (Just answered the question that I asked in the previous version of this comment.)

Comment: @sfstewman In C, byte is the unit of storage a `char` takes. So a byte can be 32 bits, or 9, anything not smaller than 8. `sizeof(type)` gives the size in units of `char`, so by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1. Since the minimal specification requires `int` to have at least 16 bits, for `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, it is possible that `sizeof(int) == 1`. But that's pretty much a theoretical scenario, 8-bit `char`s are nowadays the rule, I don't think any hardware/OS newer than 25 years has a different `char` size. But the standard allows it.