# Char size and const void*

Tags: c++, c

I have a question regarding the size of data in a const void*. In the code below, the output of the first printf is 6 while the output of the second printf is 3. Please help, I cannot find where the problem comes from. Thank you in advance

```
#define TEST "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05"

#include <stdio.h>

static void function(const void* c);

int main (void) {

    printf("TEST: %d\n",sizeof(TEST) -1);
    function(TEST);

    return 0;
}

static void function(const void* c) {
    printf("TEST: %d\n",sizeof(c) -1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, `sizeof(TEST)` is the size of the string literal, which is an array large enough to contain all the characters plus the terminator - in this case, 7 bytes.

In the second case, `sizeof(c)` is the size of a pointer - 4 bytes, on your 32-bit platform.

In general, there is no way to tell the size of an array given just a pointer to it. If it pointed to a C-style terminated string, you can measure the length with `strlen(c)`. However, in this case, it contains a null character, so there's no way to determine the length.

In C++, you could use a template, rather than `sizeof`, to get the size of an array:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) {return N;}
```

This has the advantage that you'll get a compile-time error, rather than an unexpected runtime result, if you accidentally apply it to a pointer instead of an array.

Comment: I tries with strlen(c) but I get 0 for the size. Can you give more details please. Thank you!

Comment: @user3821117: Your string starts with a null character, so it will appear to have zero length. Since it's not a valid C-style string, there's no way to find the length.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator return the number of bytes of either a type name or an expression with respect to `sizeof(char)`. Has the following syntax:

```
sizeof unary-expression 
sizeof ( type-name )
```

If it's a unary-expression and it's a string literal like you `sizeof(TEST)` it does return the count of bytes in this string, including null-byte-terminattor. But if it's a expression like `2*p` which has `int` resulting type, the expression is evaluated at compile-time (without any side-effect) and the size of resulting-type (`int`) is returned, as  `sizeof(int)`

Or if it's `type-name` like in your `sizeof(c)` it return the platform-independent number of bytes of this type. e.g, `sizeof(int)` on 32-bit machine is `4` bytes.

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size in number of `char`s

Comment: @clcto, `sizeof` is always measured in bytes. `char` is one byte.

Comment: @chris no `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1, while the number of bytes in a char is implementation defined

Comment: @clcto: What do you mean? In C and C++, a `char` is one byte, by definition.

Comment: @MikeSeymour so a byte isn't defined as 8 bits?

Comment: @clcto, C: `The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
expression or the parenthesized name of a type.` C++: `The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand.` And a byte is `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Comment: I edited a bit my answer to try make it more clear.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: @clcto: "so a byte isn't defined as 8 bits?" No. A byte is defined as the smallest addressable object, with `CHAR_BIT` bits. It's 8 bits on most popular platforms, but there are platforms (e.g. DSPs and old-school mainframes) with differently sized bytes. (I once had to write string-handling functions on a platform with 24-bit bytes, which I won't recommend if you're looking for fun.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Did you have three characters per `char`? I can't see that being too fun.

Comment: @chris: Yes: not enough RAM to waste on one word per character. Better still, the compiler writer didn't agree with the C library writer on which ordering to use, so string literals had to be written `"leH\0ol"` to be compatible with the library.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Oh man.