# C cast and char signedness

Tags: c, char, signedness

So lately, I read on an issue regarding the three distinct types in C, char/unsigned char/signed char. The problem that I now encounter is not something I have experienced up till now (my program works correctly on all tested computers and only targets little-endian (basically all modern desktops and servers using Windows/Linux right?). I frequently reuse a char array I defined for holding a "string" (not a real string of course) as temporary variables. E.g. instead of adding another char to the stack I just reuse one of the members like array[0]. However, I based this tactic on the fact that a char would always be signed, until I read today that it actually depends on the implementation. What will happen if I now have a char and I assign a negative value to it?

```
char unknownsignedness = -1;
```

If I wrote

```
unsigned char A = -1;
```

I think that the C-style cast will simply reinterpret the bits and the value that A represents as an unsigned type becomes different. Am I right that these C-Style casts are simply reinterpretation of bits? I am now referring to signed <-> unsigned conversions.

So if an implementation has char as unsigned, would my program stop working as intended? Take the last variable, if I now do

```
if (A == -1)
```

I am now comparing a unsigned char to a signed char value, so will this simply compare the bits not caring about the signedness or will this return false because obviously A cannot be -1? I am confused what happens in this case. This is also my greatest concern, as I use chars like this frequently.

Comment: What casting? There's no casting anywhere. And if you want to store binary (non-character) data use the better (IMO) `int8_t` or `uint8_t` standard types.

Comment: My implementation does not support C99, i thought int8_t were for that version

Comment: And if I assign a signed value to an unsigned value, will there be no casting? Or does casting only happen when the data sizes do not match?

Comment: There's automatic conversion, not casting. Casting is when you write something like `(unsigned char) -1`

Comment: If indeed as in the example above I assign a negative value to an unsigned data type, what happens? Are the bits reinterpreted? Or are the bits themselves changed? And also what happens in the comparison (my last example in the question).

Comment: "C-Style casts". What other casts are there in C?

Comment: Yes c-style casts I just mean casts in C in general ;p, so in the examples I gave in the questions, there should be castings right>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code prints `No`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    unsigned char a;

    a = -1;

    if(a == -1)
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The code `a = -1` assigns an implementation-defined value to `a`; on most machines, a will be 255.  The test `a == -1` compares an `unsigned char` to an `int`, so the usual promotion rules apply; hence, it is interpreted as

```
`(int)a == -1`
```

Since `a` is 255, `(int)a` is still 255, and the test yields false.

Comment: "implementation-defined value" That would be `UCHAR_MAX` in all conforming implementations.

Comment: I think I see it: I have the go back to my code and change all the char somevariable = negative value and similar comparisons, as in case char is implemented as unsigned, the program will stop working  correctly in some cases. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned char a = -1;
```

ISO/IEC 9899:1999 says in 6.3.1.3/2:

> if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type

We add `(UCHAR_MAX+1)` to `-1` once, and the result is `UCHAR_MAX`, which is obviously in range for `unsigned char`.

if (a == -1)

There's a long passage in 6.3.1.8/1:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

The rank of `unsigned char` is less than that of `int`.

If `int` can represent all the values that `unsigned char` can (which is usually the case), then both operands are converted to `int`, and the comparison returns `false`.

If `int` cannot represent all values in `unsigned char`, which can happen on rare machines with `sizeof(int)==sizeof(char)`, then both are converted to `unsigned int`, `-1` gets converted to `UINT_MAX` which happens to be the same as `UCHAR_MAX`, and the comparison returns `true`.

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned char A = -1;
```

results in 255. There is no reinterpretation upon assignment or initialization. A `-1` is just a bunch of `1` bits in two's complement notation and 8 of them are copied verbatim.

Comparisons are a bit different, as the literal `-1` is of `int` type.

```
if (A == -1)
```

will do a promotion (implicit cast) `(int)A` before comparison, so you end up comparing 255 with -1. Not equal.

And yes, you have to be careful with plain `char`.

Comment: "results in 255". That's if your `char` is 8 bits. Not guaranteed. "8-bit machine, where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`". `int` is at least 16 bits.

Comment: Agreed. I assumed char is 8 bit. Has anyone ever seen something different? Edited.

Comment: "Has anyone ever seen something different?" Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Answer (score -1):

I think this question is best answered by a quick example (warning: C++, but see explanation for my reasoning):

```
char c = -1;
unsigned char u = -1;
signed char s = -1;
if (c == u)
        printf("c == u\n");
if (s == u)
        printf("s == u\n");
if (s == c)
        printf("s == c\n");
if (static_cast<unsigned char>(s) == u)
        printf("(unsigned char)s == u\n");
if (c == static_cast<char>(u))
        printf("c == (char)u\n");
```

The output:

```
s == c
(unsigned char)s == u
c == (char)u
```

C is treating the values differently when used as-is, but you are correct in that casting will just reinterpret the bits. I used a C++ `static_cast` here instead to show that the compiler is okay with doing this casting. In C, you would just cast by prefixing the type in parenthesis. There is no compiler checking to ensure that the cast is safe in C.

Comment: This was a C question.  C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @jch: Read the first line saying to see the explanation for using C++ in this example.

Comment: So if I take my example from the question "A == -1", I have to explicitly cast as "(signed char)A == -1" in order to get it work?

Comment: @user209347 correct. The `unsigned` value `-1` is `255`.