# What's the use of the int type in C?

Tags: c, types, integer, long-integer, short

I read that C compilers must allocate 2 bytes for the type *short* and must allocate 4 bytes for the type *long*. So, depending on the system the type *int* can have 2 bytes or 4 bytes. So, what's the purpose of it? If we need a 2 byte number, we can use *short* and if we need a 4 byte number, we can use *long*. I feel like *int* is like gambling if the system is 16-bit or not.
(I generally don't understand why C can't decide by itself how much memory is needed for number, just like Python does)

Comment: "C compilers must allocate 2 bytes for the type short and must allocate 4 bytes for the type long" -- this is incorrect, the only requirement for the sizes of integer types is that `sizeof(char) == 1`. In fact, on my system, `long` is 64-bit. (**edit** i am wrong)

Comment: Oh, I read this in my textbook..

Comment: You might want to get a different textbook

Comment: Well, there are many incorrect text-books out there. THough in this case, it might be part of "lie-to-children", or the author simply not being aware that `char` might be anything but 8 bits big.

Comment: @Adrian: His textbook is correct. `short` must be at least 16 bits, `int` at least 16, and `long` at least 32. See [C data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), or the standard.

Comment: @Adrian Any references?

Comment: @JonPurdy Well, this textbook didn't say "at least", it said "must have"..

Comment: To your last part, the C standard cannot prescribe the exact behavior and width of each type, because, in contrast to python, it aims for being usable and efficient on a wide range of hardware (which is nearly equal with "all systems which exist").

Comment: If it says something like "some type" must be at least two bytes big, it is simply wrong. A valid way is making a byte 64 bit long, and all types one byte.

Comment: @Deduplicator Can you post some code which will make a byte 64 bits long? This seems very interesting :)

Comment: I haven't yet written a C compiler, sorry. Though, take a look at compilers for signal processors, some of them have decided that 64 bit is the most and the least size a type should have.

Comment: It is true that varying `int` size is not a good idea. But it is implemented in this way and we cannot change it now.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That’s true, but in practice, all commonly used architectures since the 1980s have `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: @JonPurdy: If you ignore signal processors and such, quite certain. If you don't, it's at least overwhelming.

Comment: @i486 Is it really a bad idea? Isn't `int` the size that the system can do operations on the fastest. When specifying the size of the int is important there are `int8_t`, `int16_t` etc from `stdint.h`

Comment: The problem is that the main reason for varying `int` is portability of software. You define `int` and get optimal size on different platforms. BUT this is the reason for thousands of errors. If you think that standard type must be variable size `int` and use definition like `int32_t` - I can say: why not the opposite scheme? `int32` can be built-in type and you may define "portable" `int` in `stdint.h`. (This cannot be changed now, but it could be the reality.)

Comment: "Isn't int the size that the system can do operations on the fastest" Very useful fact, but can somebody also approve that?

Comment: If C uses arbitrary precision arithmetic in every cases then it's extremely bad for performance and memory

Comment: @JonPurdy a lot of DSPs nowadays have 16/24 or 32-bit `CHAR_BIT` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char?lq=1 some other "strange" architectures with `CHAR_BIT != 8` are also [in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about?lq=1)

Comment: O/T, re the question you just deleted: Python is very dynamic, virtually everything can be patched at runtime (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29488561/3001761). However, although it has some support for functional paradigms, it is nowhere near Lisp in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B, the ancestor of C, the only type was `int`. It was the size of a “machine word”, which is generally to say the size of a register—16 bits on a 16-bit system, 32 bits on a 32-bit system, and so forth. C simply preserved this type. `short` and `long` were introduced as ways of controlling storage space when less or more range was needed. This matters when available memory is constrained: why allocate a `long` when you know a value will never exceed the range of a `short`?

> I generally don't understand why C can’t decide by itself how much memory is needed for number, just like Python does

Python decides this dynamically, using an [arbitrary-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) representation. C decides this statically, and requires that it be specified by the programmer. There are statically typed languages in which type annotations are not required, due to [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference). If you want arbitrary-precision integers in C, you can use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), which provides `mpz_t` and a host of other types and functions for arbitrary-precision arithmetic.