# Changing the __name__ of a generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

Given the following setup:

```
def mapper(f):
    def wrapper(items):
        for x in items:
            yield f(x)
    wrapper.__name__ = f.__name__ # This has no effect!
    return wrapper

@mapper
def double(x):
    return x * 2
```

The decorator works as expected:

```
>>> [x for x in double([1,2,3])]
[2, 4, 6]
```

However its `__name__` is not `double` as desired:

```
>>> double([1,2]).__name__
"wrapper"
```

Is it possible to force the name of the generator?
Alternatively, is it possible to dig around in the generator object and retrieve the name `double`?

Comment: I think you need `functools.wraps`. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do/309000#309000

Comment: @Pynchia: which does exactly the same thing (plus other attribute copies).

Comment: I think the real question here is *"how can you re`__name__` a generator object?"*; the fact that you want to do so within a decorator is incidental.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I've amended the title.

Comment: @JoeHalliwell Just wondering why you want to change __name__?

Comment: Hi @Scott, **changing** the name of the generator was just a means to an end: that of **preserving** the function name when transforming it via a decorator. (My example was intended to suggest a reasonable use case along those lines.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only copied across the name to the function. The generator object produced still uses the old name set at compile time.

You would have to set that name *each time* a new generator object is being produced; unfortunately, the attribute is *read-only* for generators:

```
>>> def gen():
...     yield None
... 
>>> gen().__name__
'gen'
>>> gen().__name__ = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: attribute '__name__' of 'generator' objects is not writable
```

The name is baked into the code object:

```
>>> gen.__code__.co_name
'gen'
```

so the only way you can change this is to *re-build* the code object (and by extension, the function):

```
def rename_code_object(func, new_name):
    code_object = func.__code__
    function, code = type(func), type(code_object)
    return function(
        code(
            code_object.co_argcount, code_object.co_nlocals,
            code_object.co_stacksize, code_object.co_flags,
            code_object.co_code, code_object.co_consts,
            code_object.co_names, code_object.co_varnames,
            code_object.co_filename, new_name,
            code_object.co_firstlineno, code_object.co_lnotab,
            code_object.co_freevars, code_object.co_cellvars),
        func.__globals__, new_name, func.__defaults__, func.__closure__)
```

This creates a new function and code object, using `new_name` to replace the old name:

```
>>> new_name = rename_code_object(gen, 'new_name')
>>> new_name.__name__
'new_name'
>>> new_name().__name__
'new_name'
>>> new_name()
<generator object new_name at 0x10075f280>
```

Using this in your decorator:

```
def mapper(f):
    def wrapper(items):
        for x in items:
            yield f(x)
    return rename_code_object(wrapper, f.__name__)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def mapper(f):
...     def wrapper(items):
...         for x in items:
...             yield f(x)
...     return rename_code_object(wrapper, f.__name__)
... 
>>> @mapper
... def double(x):
...     return x * 2
... 
>>> double([1, 2])
<generator object double at 0x10075f370>
>>> list(double([1, 2]))
[2, 4]
```

As of Python 3.5, generator objects take their `__name__` from the function object rather than from their code object `co_name` attribute, see [issue #21205](https://bugs.python.org/issue21205); the attribute became writable in the process.

Comment: Unfortunately this raises an error when you call it:

`AttributeError: attribute '__name__' of 'generator' objects is not writable`

Comment: @JoeHalliwell: way ahead of you here, let me dig up how to re-create code objects for a sec. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters That won't help too much as `gi_code` is readonly as well.

Comment: Ew. Maybe one could do something (horrendous) with an eval().

Comment: @JoeHalliwell Yeah, this is not going to be pretty ;)

Comment: @JoeHalliwell: it's horrendous, but no eval required.

Comment: That is indeed horrendous, but it's *exactly* what I was looking for!  Thanks @MartijnPieters :)

Comment: Note that in newer python versions: you may get the error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)` because `types.CodeType` takes `code_object.co_argcount, code_object.co_kwonlyargcount, code_object.co_nlocals,` instead of `code_object.co_argcount, code_object.co_nlocals,`

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane: yes, the `types.CodeType` object arguments are highly version specific.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [Python 3.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/65404) both the `__name__` and `__qualname__` attributes are modifiable.

I suggest using [functools.wraps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in your decorator, which will automatically assign both of these values to the generator function.