# Function decorated using functools.wraps raises TypeError with the name of the wrapper. Why? How to avoid?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, functools

```
def decorated(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper():
        return f()
    return wrapper

@decorated
def g():
    pass
```

`functools.wraps` does its job at preserving the name of `g`:

```
>>> g.__name__
'g'
```

But if I pass an argument to `g`, I get a `TypeError` containing the name of the wrapper:

```
>>> g(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: wrapper() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Where does this name come from? Where is it preserved? And is there a way to make the exception look like `g() takes no arguments`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29488327/3001761

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name comes from the code object; both the function and the code object (containing the bytecode to be executed, among others) contain that name:

```
>>> g.__name__
'g'
>>> g.__code__.co_name
'wrapper'
```

The attribute on the code object is read-only:

```
>>> g.__code__.co_name = 'g'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

You'd have to create a whole new code object to rename that, see [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488327/changing-the-name-of-a-generator/29488561#29488561) where I defined a function to do that; using the `rename_code_object()` function on your decorated function:

```
>>> g = rename_code_object(g, 'g')
>>> g(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Note, however, that this will entirely mask what code was being run! You generally want to see that a decorator wrapper was involved; it is the wrapper that throws the exception, not the original function, after all.

Comment: Indeed I've just linked to another answer of yours where you show how to do just that! After `g = rename_code_object(g, 'g')`, the error message becomes `TypeError: g() takes no arguments (1 given)` as desired.

Answer (score 1):

[Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29919965/4518341) covers your first two questions, but there's a better solution: don't make any assumptions about `f`'s arguments, instead forward all arguments from `wrapper()` to `f()`:

```
import functools

def decorated(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  # <- Take any arguments
        return f(*args, **kwargs)  # <- Forward
    return wrapper

@decorated
def g():
    pass

g(1)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wja/testdir/tmp.py", line 15, in <module>
    g(1)
  File "/home/wja/testdir/tmp.py", line 8, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: g() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: This is indeed another answer to my third question. One difference (neither good nor bad) with the previous solution is that the call stack shows two levels instead of one, and shows the internal name of the wrapped function, because the error is detected inside the wrapper instead of when calling the wrapper.