# C bitwise operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'm working with CodeVisionAVR Evaluation V2.05.0 which use C Compiler Reference.I met a problem when I tried this code:

```
unsigned int n;
long int data;
data|=(1<<n);
```

the problem is when n is Greater than 15 the value of data does not change. Although when I try:

```
data|=(1<<16);
```

the result is correct.
any help pleas.

Comment: try this: `data |= ((long) 1) << 16`

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Is `sizeof(int)==2`?

Comment: how long an `int` is in your compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the type of `1` is (as always) `int`. So, if `sizeof (int)` is smaller than `sizeof (long)`, it stands to reason that you can't shift an `int` over all the bits in a `long`.

The solution is of course to use an (unsigned) long constant:

```
data |= 1UL << n;
```

I made it unsigned since unsigned integers are better suited for bitwise operators. The type of the literal `1UL` is `unsigned long`. I find using suffixes nicer than casting, since it's way shorter and part of the literal itself, rather than having a literal of the wrong type and casting it.

Many people seem to expect that in an expression such as:

```
unsigned long long veryBig = 1 << 35; /* BAD CODE */
```

the right-hand side should somehow magically adapt to the "needs" of the left-hand side, and thus become of type `unsigned long long` (which I just assume has at least 35 bits, this is of course not portable but it's concise). That does not happen, C doesn't work like that. The expression is evaluated, *then* it's converted (if necessary) to the type on the left for the assignment to work.

Answer (score 0):

If `sizeof(int)==2` then `1<<n` is of type `int`. And `1<<16 == 0`. Thus `data` is not changed.

Comment: 16-bit int doesn't necessarily mean that `sizeof(int) == 2`, because `CHAR_BIT` can be 16

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc What architecture? Won't be `sizeof(int)<=2` anyway?

Comment: There's no limit in C and C++ standard about any types' sizes except their ranges and `sizeof(char) == 1`. Don't you see `sizeof(int) == 4` which is larger than 2 on most architectures? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: Some more examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc OK, I got it. But this one seems not to be such a case, and writing `sizeof(int)==2` is shorter than 'int type is 16-bits long'.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `int` is 16 bits. When you use integer literals the compiler can work out that the result is larger than fits in an `int`, and will optimize the whole shift-operation away, but when you use a variable, the compiler can't do that because it doesn't know the value of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

i want to thank everyone, by your answer I really understood the problem
 which is 1 in `(1<<n)` is integer with size 2 bytes.
i fixed the problem by let 1 be unsigned long `(1UL<<n)`.
this is first question for me and you are awesome guys.
thank you and I'm sorry for my bad english.