# How can you assign an integer value to a char datatype?

Tags: c

In the below code how can a `char` data type be assigned to an integer variable (as in char data type alphabets are written in single quote) and while printing the char data type it is using %d subscript instead of using %c ?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
    int main()
    {
        char a = 30, b = 40, c = 10;
        char d = (a * b) / c;//a char value is storing integer value ?how ?
        printf ("%d ", d); 
        return 0;
    }
```

how can a char data type is storing integer value

Comment: When you store an `int` into a `char`, it just chops off all but the low 8 bits.

Comment: Because, char are data types which hold 1 byte (8 bits) of data. So in  char you can store integer values that can be represented by eight bits. That is 0-255 in normal case. So you can store values in that range in char. How ever if you try to store a value out side that range (say 258) then u may have issues. Try it.

Answer (score 3):

`char`s are just small integers that can hold values in range `[-128;127]`.
 (On some systems it may be `[0;255]`. On very rare platforms it can have another size, but you probably will never see these cases.)

Character literals like `'0'` are just codes of corresponding symbols. For example, `'0'` is equal to `48`.
(On most encodings. Another values are very rare.)

---

Why `%d` works for `char`? Because when you pass `char`s and `short`s to `...` function argument, they are automatically converted to ints.
And `printf` is declared as `printf(const char *, ...);`.

Comment: [`char` being signed or unsigned is an implementation decision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). [`CHAR_BIT` is usually 8, but not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char). [`'0' == 48` in ASCII and some other encodings, but not all encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Comment: @BillLynch I intentionally simplified my answer for OP. Ok, I'll add this information.

Comment: The main offender is the signed or unsigned of `char`. That can easily vary over platforms that regular folks may deal with. The others are far less common.

Comment: @BillLynch: True, platforms with plain `char` being unsigned are much more common than systems with `CHAR_BIT > 8`. It's also worth noting that all members of the basic character set are required to have non-negative values; a `char` might or might not be able to store a negative value, but `'a'` is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the calculation `30 * 40` does not overflow, because the operands are promoted to `int` type and converted back to `char` after the division.

When passed to a variadic function like `printf` the `char` is again promoted to `int`.

Aside: for the `float` type, that too is promoted when passed to `printf`, to `double`. This is why the `printf` format specifier `%f` works for both `float` and `double`. As for calculations, it is an implementation decision whether or not to promote `float` to `double`.