# Implicit integer type conversion in C

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

I understand the implicit conversions of the C language between integer and floating point types, but I have a question for signed/unsigned implicit type conversions.

If you add, for example, an `unsigned char`  and a `signed int`, what will be the resulting type? Would it be an `unsigned int`, a `signed int`, or something else?

I don't see anything specific in the C99 ANSI standard about this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "implicit cast" in C. A *cast* is an operator, consisting of a type name in parentheses; it specifies a conversion. C has implicit conversions and explicit conversions; casts are by definition explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C99, the reference is 6.3.1.8 "Usual arithmetic conversions".

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a *common real type* for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions:*
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>     corresponding real type is `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>     corresponding real type is `double`.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other
>     operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>     corresponding real type is `float`. 51)
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>     following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>       integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>       converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>       equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>       signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>       all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>       the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>       operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>       corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Addition performs the usual arithmetic conversions, so, when adding `unsigned char` and `signed int`, either:

- first the `unsigned char` is promoted to `int`, and then both types are the same, so the result has type `int`, or
- (uncommon) `int` cannot represent all possible `unsigned char` values. In this case, `unsigned char` is promoted to `unsigned int`, and the third sub-bullet applies: `unsigned int` has equal rank to `int`, so the `int` operand is converted to `unsigned int`, and the result has type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

It will almost certainly be a `signed int` and it depends on the system where the code runs. Check the paragraph *Integral promotion* [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

> `unsigned char` or `unsigned short` can be converted to `int` if it can hold
>   its entire value range, and `unsigned int` otherwise.

On a POSIX system for example it will definitely be a `signed int` as a `char` is always 8bits and an `int` is at least 16bits. Therefore an `int` can represent every possible value of an `unsigned char`. There are apparently [systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char) where `char` is more that 8bits.

Comment: Be careful: "unsigned int otherwise". Your own cite contradicts your answer.

Comment: You should use [this link instead](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) for C (yours is for C++).

Comment: @pablo1977 It is indeed possible to have a promotion to `unsigned int` in some (obscure) systems. For example both `char` and `int` could have a size of 16bits. Although I am not sure if such a system actually exists!

Comment: Thanks Chrono Kitsune. I modified the link.

Comment: @Manos Nikolaidis: Yes, there exists. The topic was ilustrated a few montths ago here in SO, but I don't remember exactly where the post is.

Comment: A singed int results from a call to the function toastInt()