# Is it guaranteed that size_t, vector::size_type, etc typedefs won't bind to a char type?

Tags: c++, char, size-t

It is definitely possible that `cstdint` typedefs bind to char variables. For example, it is very likely that `uint_least8_t` binds to `unsigned char`, and `int_least8_t` binds to `signed char`.

Does the Standard guarantee that similar thing won't happen to `size_t` or similar types? Or is there at least a purely theoretical chance that such types will bind to some char types, like `unsigned char` or maybe even `wchar_t`?

Comment: Sure, if `unsigned char` is enough bits, then there's no reason it can't be used for `size_t`.

Comment: So, `cout << vector.size()` may be a dangerous operation? Not to mention `vector<int>::size_type n; cin >> n; vector<int> t(n)`?

Comment: I suppose so, if you have a weird enough implementation.

Answer (score 4):

All we know about `std::size_t` is:

> The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size
>   in bytes of any object.

If `unsigned char` fulfills this condition, it may be used as `std::size_t`.

However, this concern is purely theoretical as there is not a single real platform (that I know of) where <s>`unsigned char` would be wide enough</s> (alright, that was wrong) a char type is used as `std::size_t` or the like.

If you are super paranoid, you can promote the value to at least `int` with the unary `+`:

```
std::cout << +vector.size();
```

This will print the number even if the size type would be a character type.

For reading you can use variables of type `std::common_type<unsigned int, std::size_t>::type` (probably through a `typedef`) and then do a bounds check in case `sizeof(int) > sizeof(std::size_t)`.

Comment: True with `std::cout`, but things get a little bit harder with `std::cin`

Comment: I'm not sure your last paragraph is entirely correct. There are C implementations for DSPs (Digital Signal Processors) with `CHAR_BIT > 8`; in particular, I think `CHAR_BIT == 32` exists. Still, on such a system `unsigned int` is probably also 32 bits, and would be a better candidate for `size_t`, so there's still no good reason for `size_t` to be a character type.

Comment: @KeithThompson Alright, I added a weasel phrase to the paragraph.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char there *are* machines where a char would be definitely wide enough. *edit* I come late...

Comment: @gaazkam You can start to read variables of type `std::common_type<unsigned int, std::size_t>::type`. That is at least as big as `std::size_t` and at least an `unsigned int` and then do a bounds check in case of `sizeof(int) > sizeof(std::size_t)`. :)

Comment: to be honest, I'm unsure why is it guaranteed that `std::common_type<unsigned int, std::size_t>::type` will necessarily not be a char type? (my first idea was to read to a helper variable of type `decltype(+v)`, where `v` is a variable to be read into which might be of type `char`, and then do a bounds check and copy helper variable into `v`, but i found this a little ugly)

Comment: @gaazkam The `common_type` thing will work because `int` has a higher conversion rank than `char`, and the `wchar` stuff does not matter for `cin`. Considering the "ugly" part: I guess you'll have to live with that if you are going to be that paranoid.

Comment: @gaazkam But again, I feel like you are being overly paranoid here. Implementers do not actively seek to troll their customers.

Comment: No, not paranoid. Just perfectionistic. I simply noticed that my solutions of tasks on UVA rely much on some de-facto standards rather than The Standard, and just as an exercise and out of curiosity I started wondering how could I re-write them in such a way they would be guaranteed to be correct as per the C++ standard.

Comment: @gaazkam i'm probably the biggest pedant on this site but I would be happy to assume for practical reasons that nobody will ever make `size_t` a character type!   (Possibly someone could submit that for the next C++ standard)

Answer (score 0):

Document [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) is the closest approximation to C++11 that is readily available online for free.  The relevant sections are 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental], 18.2 [support.types], and 18.4 [cstdint].

All of the type names you are curious about, except `wchar_t`, are required to be `typedef`s for primitive *integer types* of the appropriate signedness.  `signed char` and `unsigned char` are considered to be primitive integer types; plain `char` is not.  `wchar_t` is special; in C++ (not C), it is a *keyword* (like `int`) and a distinct primitive type.

Plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are considered to be *character types*; `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t` are **not** character types (nor are they integer types).

So the answer is that all of the types you mention, except `wchar_t`,  *could* conceivably be defined as `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but not as plain `char`.

Yes, this is confusing.  It reflects a tangled history of varying levels of compatibility with C and changing ideas about how to handle text that can't be represented in ASCII.

Comment: `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` are all integer types. See [basic.fundamental]/7 in N3337.  Character types are a subset of integer types.

Comment: @M.M I think you have confused *integral* types with *integer* types.  I believe the types listed in [basic.fundamental]/2 and /3 are meant to be the *only* integer types.  Note that `char`, `wchar_t`, and `char*_t` do not appear in those lists.

Comment: [basic.fundamental]/7 says "A synonym for integral type is integer type."

Comment: @M.M. You're right, but that's a bug in the standard (dating all the way back to C++98), because there are a bunch of places where language like "integral constant expression *with integer type*" is used with the intent to *exclude* character and enumeration types.  For instance, 4.10's definition of a null pointer constant:  If [basic.fundamental]/7 is taken at face value then the "with integer type" part is vacuous and `'\0'` is a valid null pointer constant in C++, which it isn't supposed to be.

Comment: `'\0'` *is* a valid null pointer constant - current compilers accept it (as they should, imo)

Comment: @M.M All I can say is that I am certain that the C++ committee intends `'\0'` *not* to be a valid null pointer constant.  Maybe one of us should file a defect report.

Comment: Is that written down somewhere?