# what is the difference in defining the 'byte' in terms of computer memory and in terms of C++?

Tags: c++

This is with reference to the text from C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata-

A byte means a 8-bit unit of memory in the sense of unit of measurement that describes the amount of memory in a computer.
However, C++ defines byte differently. The C++ byte consists of at least enough adjacent bits to accommodate the basic character set for the implementation.

Can you please explain if a C++ compiler have 16-bit byte whereas the system has 8-bit byte then how will the program run on such system?

Comment: `A byte means a 8-bit unit of memory` no, it does not (though it IS 8 bit on almost all platforms),

Comment: "**[intro.memory]/1** The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the *byte*. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined. The least significant bit is called the *low-order bit*; the most significant bit is called the *high-order bit*. The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address."

Comment: It would be nice if someone could come up with an example of an actual C++ implementation on a system with `CHAR_BIT != 8`.

Comment: @FelixDombek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: It's worth noting that POSIX mandates 8-bit byte.

Comment: Commentary: it's also worth noting that C++ Primer Plus is generally considered to be written by someone who doesn't know what he's talking about. (e.g. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-C++-Primer-Plus-and-C++-Primer-for-beginners)

Comment: @FelixDombek: Texas Instruments' C55x series of fixed-point digital signal processors have word (16-bit) addressing; they can't address with any smaller granularity. Accordingly, a `char` is 16 bits in size. See [page 7-19 of its C compiler user guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru281f/spru281f.pdf).

Comment: @FelixDombek: Why? C++ is an abstraction over physical machines. That is its purpose.

Comment: @JasonR I'm getting flashbacks of when I had to process 8-bit byte streams on that horrible platform.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is interesting to know if this particular abstraction was ever used. The C55x seems to have a C++ compiler, so it has – but strangely, a `long long` is 40 bytes according to the manual, I wonder if `sizeof` returns 2.5 there? Seems to be deliberately non-standard anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What the author wants to say about the size of a byte is that, quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte):

> The popularity of major commercial computing architectures has aided in the ubiquitous acceptance of the 8-bit size.

On the other hand, the unit of memory in C++ is given by the built-in type `char`; under some implementation, a `char` may **not** be an 8-bit memory chunk; though, in your C++ program every [`sizeof(T)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) will be expressed in multiples of `sizeof(char)`, that is equal to `1` by definition.

The number of bit in a byte for a particular implementation is recorded into the macro `CHAR_BIT`, defined inside the standard header [`<climits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits). It is guaranteed that `char` is at least 8-bits.

Finally, this is the definition of *byte* given by the C++ Standard (§1.7, **intro.memory**) :

> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the *byte*. A byte is at least large enough to contain
>   any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8
>   encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementationdefined.
>   The least significant bit is called the *low-order bit*; the most significant bit is called the *high-order
>   bit*. The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every
>   byte has a unique address.

Comment: `in your C++ program every sizeof(T) will be expressed in multiples of sizeof(char)` ... unsurprisingly, since `sizeof(char)==1`, by definition. Any integral number, including `sizeof(T)`, is necessarily a multiple of 1, so the property as stated is not particularly interesting.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You're right, not a big deal. What I wanted to point out was actually that `char` is the unit of measure for other types, for what regards sizes.

Answer (score 6):

> A byte means a 8-bit unit of memory.

That is incorrect.

> However, C++ defines byte differently.

That is also incorrect.

In both C++ terminology and general parlance, a byte is the minimum unit of memory. An 8-bit byte is known as an *octet*.

> Can you please explain if a C++ compiler have 16-bit byte whereas the system has 8-bit byte then how will the program run on such system?

It won't. If you compile a program for an architecture whose bytes are 16-bit, it will not run on a computer with an architecture whose bytes are 8-bit.

You have to compile for the processor you're using.

Comment: That's why the FTP specification talks about octets instead of bytes - when it was being written, not all architectures had standardized on an 8 bit byte.

Comment: @sashoalm: And they still haven't!

Comment: I regularly work with modern processors with 16 and 32 bit byte sizes.

Comment: @Graznarak - I think you are talking about words. A byte is the smallest addressable unit of memory. The word is the group of bytes on which of the machine instructions act. The instructions on sixteen bit computer most efficiently work on pairs of bytes. The instructions on a 32 bit computer most efficiently work on two pairs, or four bytes. A word used to correspond to the width of the data bus hardware.

Comment: @BobWakefield I don't know, but I think Graznarak is talking about processors, where the smallest addressable unit really is 16 or 32 bits. Probably DSPs.

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with DSPs.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be machines that had either variable byte size, or a byte size smaller than 8.  The spec leaves it open to implementation on the given hardware.

The DEC PDP-10 had a 36 bit word size, and you could specify the size of a byte (usually 5 7 bit bytes to the word...)

http://pdp10.nocrew.org/docs/instruction-set/Byte.html

Comment: C++ requires `CHAR_BIT` ≥ 8.

Comment: Fair enough.  The minimum addressable unit of memory can certainly be larger than a byte.