# Is the number of bits in a byte equal to the number of bits in a type char?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Does C standard mandates it? Is there a platform where the number of bits in a byte is not equal to the number of bits in a type `char`?

Comment: These might be of interest as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit (neither answers the question completely).

Comment: Reopened. This question is different to the 8 bits in a byte duplicate: it's not about something being equal to 8 bits but rather it is about something having the same number of bits as something else.

Comment: @cdarke: to be clear, this question is not about what `CHAR_BIT` value is. It is about whether you need *all* bits in a byte to represent `char` values (no padding bits).

Comment: Yes, I get that.  You also asked if there is a platform where the number of bits in a byte is not equal to a char, and the links I gave show several discussions and examples of such platforms.  I'm not claiming your question is a duplicate.

Comment: @cdarke: I see `CHAR_BIT != 8`  platforms in your links but I do not see platforms where the number of bits is not equal (I don't see platforms where the width of a `char` is less than `CHAR_BIT` and my answer implies that no such platform may exist unless it violates the C standard). Could you post such platforms as an answer (if you see them)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Both are equal to `CHAR_BIT`<sup>*</sup>.

C standard defines `CHAR_BIT` as: *"number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)"*. c99 says explicitly: ***"A byte contains `CHAR_BIT` bits."***

*"`UCHAR_MAX` shall equal 2<sup>`CHAR_BIT`</sup> - 1"* — it means `unsigned char` requires **at least** `CHAR_BIT` bits (`char_bits >= CHAR_BIT`).

`sizeof(char) == 1` (single-byte character fits in a byte) i.e., type `char` requires **at most** `CHAR_BIT` bits (`char_bits <= CHAR_BIT`).

From `char_bits >= CHAR_BIT` and `char_bits <= CHAR_BIT` follows that `char_bits == CHAR_BIT` (no padding bits).

[POSIX says it explicitly](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html): ***"`CHAR_BIT` Number of bits in a type `char`."***

---

<sup>*</sup>: If `char` is signed and `CHAR_BIT > 8` then (without the `$6.2.6.2` quote below) it was not clear  whether `SCHAR_MIN..SCHAR_MAX` range covers all `CHAR_BIT` bits. Though the name `CHAR_BIT` communicates the intent clearly ("number of bits in `char`").

c11 says (`$6.2.6.2` in n1570 draft): *"`signed char` shall not have any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit."*

From `$6.2.5.15`:

> The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`

it follow: All `CHAR_BIT` bits are used to represent `CHAR_MIN..CHAR_MAX` range (because both `signed` and `unsigned char` type use all bits).

For comparison, unlike `char`; `_Bool` may use less bits `$6.7.2.1.4(122)`:

> While the number of bits in a `_Bool` object is at least **`CHAR_BIT`**, the width (number of sign and value bits) of a `_Bool` may be just **1 bit**.

Comment: Sadly I can't add a new answer, as the question is closed, but buried in the tech overview for the C55x: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru393/spru393.pdf you can see that the system is configurable for byte sizes from 8-48 bits (some 54x series don't offer 8-bit, but I couldn't find public docs).  The "new" c99 compliant tools make `CHAR_BIT == 8` and `sizeof char == 1` because that's what the standard says (well, `sizeof char` was always 1 by definition), but the byte size in the CPU is still not 8 bits in most cases, and this does affect the memory you allocate and the code you write.

Comment: @NickBastin: you can add answer now.

Comment: @NickBastin: ISO C permits any value >=8 for `CHAR_BIT`. POSIX requires `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Both require `sizeof (char) == 1`.