# C - Why does adding numbers to a char reset at 255?

Tags: c, char

I'm not sure how to unlock characters past 255 automatically.

```
char f;
f = 'k';
printf("%d\n", f);
```

Results in `107`. No surprise.

```
f += 500;
printf("%d\n", f);
```

Results in `95`. It seems this has been modulo divided by 255.

```
printf("%c\n", 607);
```

Results in `_`. There are many more characters that extend into the thousands as well. How come adding a value and making a char go past 255 forces a modulo operation? I need to go past 255 for the sake of a hash function.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one byte. So it could not be greater than 255. If you need more, use `wchar_t` or its analogs.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to read this: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @Ari0nhh It's true that `sizeof(char)` is one, it's not necessarily true that it *can't* be greater than 255. `sizeof(char)` can be 1 but it *could* consist of 16 bits.

Comment: Just go read chapter one of a C programming book. That being said, you shouldn't use `char` to store numbers for other reasons, namely the implementation-defined signedness.

Comment: @P.P. In C, yes, but POSIX mandates byte, thus `char` to be exactly 8 bits.

Comment: @Lundin I need to enumerate them for a hash function and they will need to be a huge range of characters after reconversion. Admittedly the assignment question this is from is terrible but unfortunately marks have to be obtained.

Comment: It seems that in your case, `char` is `unsigned` and its range is 0-255. When it goes beyond 255, the value wraps-around which is the same as mod 256

Comment: @el.pescado: A "byte" is not defined to be 8 bits. POSIX might define a byte in the standard to have 8 bits, but the reverse is not true. Anyway, C is not POSIX and there is no indicator the question is about POSIX. The C standard only uses `char` and "byte" synonymously, but does not enforce the bitwidth - that's why `CHAR_BIT` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char` is a byte in memory. So you can not store values > 255 because it has only 8 bits (assuming that on your platform a char is defined as a byte of 8 bits). When the value is more than 255, it overflows.

Furthermore, you don't know if a `char` is unsigned (values can be between 0 and 255) or signed (values can be between -128 and 127).

You can use another type than `char` if you want to store values > 255.

Comment: `char` are *at least* a byte,  but your reasoning about overflow is right

Comment: @Garf365: `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, but this is not true: `char` is 8 bits, `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a `char`: [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/1606345)

Comment: Sorry I downvoted this answer because it is rather wrong, even with char bits as 8.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` data type is an `8-bit` field, with a maximum total value of `255`. You need to use a `16-bit` value if you wish to work with numbers greater than 255.

`unsigned char` has a value range of `0 to 255`  
`signed char` has a value range of `-128 to 127`

Comment: I do not have them backwards.

Comment: He needs to work with unicode. `signed char` and `unsigned char` don't help here at all.

Comment: The OP uses `char` however. What range and signedness a `char` has, we cannot know, since it is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Lundin Oh good grief. How many angels can sit on the head of a pin?

Comment: @Lundin , yes, that was it.

Comment: @bolov what does unicode have to do with this? OP said he's using C, and a `char` data type, its an `8-bit field` which can be `signed` or `unsigned`

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby `char` is a *at least* one byte field

Comment: @Garf365 in what case is a `char` greater than one byte in C

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby size of type are implementation dependents

Comment: @Garf365 okay, maybe I was just thinking simply of C99

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby this is also true for C99

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always one, but according to the C standard, `CHAR_BITS` should be `>= 8`

Comment: @CoolGuy thank for precision, I totally forget this distinction. I used in past a DSP and `char` was more than 8 bits