# What counts as character type in C11?

Tags: c, char

What actually *belongs* to the "character type" in C11 — besides `char` of course?

To be more precise, the special exceptions for the character type (for example that *any* object can be accessed by an lvalue expression of character type — see §6.5/7 in C11 standard), to which concrete types do they apply? They *seem* to apply to `uint8_t` and `int8_t` from `stdint.h`, but is this guaranteed? On the other hand gcc doesn't regard `char16_t` from `uchar.h` as a "character type".

Comment: Also `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: Note that `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are just aliases for existing types.

Comment: There have been serious proposals to base `int8_t` and `uint8_t` on extended integer types, functionally identical to `signed char` and `unsigned char` respectively _except_ that they would not count as "character types" for §6.5/7.  As far as I know, no implementation has carried through this idea, but I'm not aware of any reason it's forbidden, either.  (The advantage of this would be, for instance, that you could now have string pointers that _didn't_ alias all the other pointers in the program.)

Comment: @zwol Do you mean by using `std::basic_string<uint8_t>`, etc.?

Comment: @underscore_d Essentially yes.  It would be awkward on account of all the library functions that expect plain `char*` and/or `std::string`, but it could be done.  I suspect careful use of `restrict` gets you at least 90% of the benefit, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`<sup>1</sup>.

The types `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, `char16_t`, or any type in the form `intN_t` or `charN_t`, may or may not be synonyms for a character type.

---

<sup>1</sup>(Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.5 Types 15)
The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the character types.

Comment: If `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int8_t)` then `int8_t` *is* a character type?

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats No, that is not guaranteed. It could be theoretically typedefed as an extended integer type.

Comment: @2501 The `intN_t` types are optional and cannot exist on a machine that does not have an exactly `N`-bit type. And since `char` types must be the smallest addressible unit on a machine, and must be at least 8 bits... if a machine supports the `int8_t` types, then they must be aliases to `[[un]signed] char`. Or have I missed a logical loophole somewhere? I guess some exotic machine could offer types with the same width but different signages or bit representations... making them more suited to one or the other of `char` or `intN_t`.

Comment: @underscore_d The point 2501 was making is that a system could provide types with the same size and representation but that are "technically" different types (in that signatures for functions taking one type will not match the other, etc)

Answer (score 7):

`char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are the *character types* in C11. This is the same since C89.

Treating `int8_t` (or `uint8_t`) as a *character type* has many problems.

1. They are optional.
2. They may not exist if `CHAR_BIT > 8`.
3. Defined to work if the implementation uses *2's complement* representation (which is the most common). But they are other representations, namely *1's complement* and *sign-magnitude* defined/allowed by the C standard.

Since they are, if they exist, typedef'ed to an existing type, you can probably get away with using `int8_t` or `uint8_t` as a *character type* in practice. But the standard doesn't guarantee anything and there's no reason to treat them as such anyway when you have the *real* character types.

Comment: I previously used the `cstdint` typedefs but stopped and went back to good old `char`s for precisely the reasons you gave. It just makes sense, states intent properly as per the special allowances given to `char`s, and protects against potential accidents later (on some exotic implementation).

Comment: I would like to ask, if there actually exists an implementation, where `char` is larger than one byte? If you look for example at GNU libc's memset at the lines `cccc = (unsigned char) c; cccc |= cccc << 8; cccc |= cccc << 16;` this *would* break if `char` is larger than one byte. So with GNU is seems implicitly to be guaranteed that `char` is one byte large.

Comment: See: [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char) for some examples. Yes, that'd break glibc. But glibc typically uses arch-specific assembly code for memset, memcpy etc. So, that code might not be the one *actually* used. Besides, CHAR_BIT!=8 allowance is mainly for DSPs. But you can reasonably assume CHAR_BIT=8 on most desktop systems and POSIX requires CHAR_BIT to be exactly 8 bits. But, the standard covers a lot of other systems as well.