# C: different String definition, I get different size using sizeof()

Tags: c, sizeof

I was testing the use of sizeof() for the same String content "abc". my function is like this:

```
int main(void){
    char* pass1 = "abc";
    char pass2[] = "abc";
    char pass3[4] = "abc";
    char pass4[] = "";

    scanf("%s", pass4);

    printf("sizeof(pass1) is: %lu\n", sizeof(pass1));
    printf("sizeof(pass2) is: %lu\n", sizeof(pass2));
    printf("sizeof(pass3) is: %lu\n", sizeof(pass3));
    printf("sizeof(pass4) is: %lu\n", sizeof(pass4));

    return 0;
}
```

I input "abc" for pass4, the output is like this:

```
sizeof(pass1) is: 8
sizeof(pass2) is: 4
sizeof(pass3) is: 4
sizeof(pass4) is: 1
```

I was expecting all 4s. I thought the 4 above string definitions are the same.

why sizeof(pass1) returns 8? Why sizeof(pass4) is 1?

Comment: `sizeof` yields a result of type `size_t`. The correct format for `size_t` is `"%zu"`.

Comment: This is one of those times that arrays are not pointers... they do devolve to pointers when passed into functions, but you lose this size info... in fact a common paradigm uses this to find the number of elements in an array...

Comment: [to print `size_t` use %zu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714). Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior

Comment: @GradyPlayer: `pass1` *is* a pointer.

Comment: what about pass4?

Answer (score 3):

When you take `sizeof` on a pointer type, you'll get the size in bytes of the memory address. In this case `8` is the size of the address (in bytes). `sizeof` on statically allocated read only strings in C will return the actual size in bytes of the string including the null byte.

Comment: I thought the pointer pass1 is pointing to the 8 bit character type memory address.I never defined a 8 bytes memory address for that string.

Comment: @DiWang That depend on compiler and platform, maybe you use 64-bit compiler in x64 platform. 
You can check sizeof(void*), sizeof(char*), sizeof(double*) or any pointer type, they shoule be same.

Comment: Thanks, sizeof(char*) is 8. tested on my computer.

Comment: then you should read again about pointer. It stores the address to some position in memory. The size of the pointer is 8 bytes and size of the memory region it points to in this case is 1 byte. Note that [`char` isn't necessarily 8 bits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714)

Comment: Well I added a command, now the sizeof(pass4) is 1. I am totally confused

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` gives the size of its operand.  To understand the results you are seeing, you need to understand what `pass1`, `pass2`, `pass3`, and `pass4` actually are.

`pass1` is a pointer to char (i.e. a `char *`) so `sizeof pass1` gives the size of a pointer (a variable which contains a memory address, not an array).  That is `8` with your compiler. The size of a pointer is implementation defined, so this may give different results with different compilers.   The fact you have initialised `pass1` so it points at the first character of a string literal `"abc"` does not change the fact that `pass1` is declared as a pointer, not an array.

`pass2` is an array initialised using the literal `"abc"` which - by convention - is represented in C using an array of four characters  (the three letters `'a'` to `'c'`, plus an additional character with value zero (`'\0'`).

`pass3` is also an array of four `char`, since it is declared that way `char pass3[4] = <etc>`.   If you had done `char pass3[4] = "abcdef"`, you would still find that `sizeof pass3` is `4` (and the 4 elements of `pass3` will be `'a'` to `'d'` (with other character `'e'`, `'f'`, and `'\0'` in the string literal `"abcdef"` not used to initialise `pass3`).

Since both `pass2` and `pass3` are arrays of four characters, their size is 4  (in general, the size of an array is the size of the array element multiplied by number of elements).   The standard defines `sizeof char` to be `1`, and `1*4` has a value `4`.

`pass4` is initialised using the literal `""`.   That string literal is represented using a single char with value `'\0'` (and no characters before it, since none are between the double quotes).  So `pass4` has size `1` for the same reason that `pass2` has size 4.

Comment: But pass4 has been replaced by "abc", \0 is over written. how can the size be 1 again? I have tested strlen(pass4), it returns 3, but sizeof(pass4) returns 1.

Comment: The `scanf("%s", pass4)` (which I'll point out you inserted AFTER I gave this answer) gives undefined behaviour, unless the user enters no characters before the newline.     That means anything is allowed to happen.    In practice, if you enter `abc` it will overwrite whatever memory is located immediately after `pass4`.      That doesn't change the size of `pass4` - it simply means your code overwrites memory past the end of `pass4`.   Since `strlen()` keeps walking through memory until it finds a `'\0'`, it will report `4`, but that is happenstance.

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration

```
char* pass1 = "abc";
```

in the right side used as an initializer there is a character array that has size equal to 4. String literals have types of character arrays. Take into account that string literals include the terminating zero. You can check this the following way

```
printf("sizeof( \"abc\") is: %zu\n", sizeof( "abc"));
```

In the declaration the array is used to initialize a pointer. Used as initializer of a pointer the array is implicitly converted to the pointer to its first element.

Thus the pointer `pass1` points to the first element of the string literal `"abc"`. The size of the pointer itself in your system is equal to 8 bytes.

In these declerations

```
char pass2[] = "abc";
char pass3[4] = "abc";
```

the string literal is used to initialize arrays. In this case each element of the arrays is initialized by the corresponding element of the string literal. All other elements of the arrays are zero initialized. If the size of an array is not specified then it is calculated from the number of initializers.

So in this declaration

```
char pass2[] = "abc";
```

the array `pass2` will have 4 elements because the sgtring literal provides four initializers.

In this declaration

```
char pass3[4] = "abc";
```

there is explicitly specified that the array has 4 elements.

Thus the both arrays has size equal to 4 and the pointer declared first has size of 8 bytes.