# Converting large number stored in array of u32 to bytes and back

Tags: rust

I'm doing some computational mathematics in Rust, and I have some large numbers which I store in an array of 24 values. I have functions that convert them to bytes and back, but it doesn't work fine for `u32` values, whereas it works fine for `u64`. The code sample can be found below:

```
fn main() {
    let mut bytes = [0u8; 96]; // since u32 is 4 bytes in my system, 4*24 = 96
    let mut j;
    let mut k: u32;

    let mut num: [u32; 24] = [1335565270, 4203813549, 2020505583, 2839365494, 2315860270, 442833049, 1854500981, 2254414916, 4192631541, 2072826612, 1479410393, 718887683, 1421359821, 733943433, 4073545728, 4141847560, 1761299410, 3068851576, 1582484065, 1882676300, 1565750229, 4185060747, 1883946895, 4146];
    println!("original_num: {:?}", num);

    for i in 0..96 {
        j = i / 4;
        k = (i % 4) as u32;
        bytes[i as usize] = (num[j as usize] >> (4 * k)) as u8;
    }

    println!("num_to_ytes: {:?}", &bytes[..]);
    num = [0u32; 24];

    for i in 0..96 {
        j = i / 4;
        k = (i % 4) as u32;
        num[j as usize] |= (bytes[i as usize] as u32) << (4 * k);
    }

    println!("recovered_num: {:?}", num);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fdb11b2d8fd7fc256cace5c5b6962c89&version=stable)

The above code does not retrieve the correct number from the byte array. But, if I change all `u32` to `u64`, all `4`s to `8`s, and reduce the size of `num` from 24 values to 12, it works all fine. I assume I have some logical problem for the `u32` version. The correctly working `u64` version can be found in [this Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=569917b7e971703908e5d0d3c21640e7&version=stable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Learning how to create a [MCVE](/help/mcve) is a crucial skill when programming. For example, why do you have an array at all? Why do you *reuse* variables?

Your original first number is `0x4F9B1BD6`, the output first number is `0x000B1BD6`.

Comparing the intermediate bytes shows that you have garbage:

```
let num = 0x4F9B1BD6_u32;
println!("{:08X}", num);

let mut bytes = [0u8; BYTES_PER_U32];
for i in 0..bytes.len() {
    let k = (i % BYTES_PER_U32) as u32;
    bytes[i] = (num >> (4 * k)) as u8;
}

for b in &bytes {
    print!("{:X}", b);
}
println!();
```

```
4F9B1BD6
D6BD1BB1
```

Printing out the values of `k`:

```
for i in 0..bytes.len() {
    let k = (i % BYTES_PER_U32) as u32;
    println!("{} / {}", k, 4 * k);
    bytes[i] = (num >> (4 * k)) as u8;
}
```

Shows that you are trying to shift by multiples of **4** bits:

```
0 / 0
1 / 4
2 / 8
3 / 12
```

I'm pretty sure that every common platform today uses **8** bits for a byte, not **4**.

This is *why magic numbers are bad*. If you had used constants for the values, you would have noticed the problem much sooner.

> since u32 is 4 bytes in my system

A `u32` **better** be 4 bytes on *every system* — that's why it's a *`u32`*.

---

Overall, don't reinvent the wheel. Use the byteorder crate or equivalent:

```
extern crate byteorder;

use byteorder::{BigEndian, ReadBytesExt, WriteBytesExt};

const LENGTH: usize = 24;
const BYTES_PER_U32: usize = 4;

fn main() {
    let num: [u32; LENGTH] = [
        1335565270, 4203813549, 2020505583, 2839365494, 2315860270, 442833049, 1854500981,
        2254414916, 4192631541, 2072826612, 1479410393, 718887683, 1421359821, 733943433,
        4073545728, 4141847560, 1761299410, 3068851576, 1582484065, 1882676300, 1565750229,
        4185060747, 1883946895, 4146,
    ];
    println!("original_num: {:?}", num);

    let mut bytes = [0u8; LENGTH * BYTES_PER_U32];
    {
        let mut bytes = &mut bytes[..];
        for &n in &num {
            bytes.write_u32::<BigEndian>(n).unwrap();
        }
    }

    let mut num = [0u32; LENGTH];
    {
        let mut bytes = &bytes[..];
        for n in &mut num {
            *n = bytes.read_u32::<BigEndian>().unwrap();
        }
    }

    println!("recovered_num: {:?}", num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I got bitten by the magic numbers, didn't recognize that shift amount.

Comment: Actually I am not sure that `u32` is necessarily 4 bytes on every system. In C, `uint32_t` is not necessarily available on all platforms, because some platforms don't have 8-bits bytes (ie `CHAR_BIT != 8`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've always been under the impression that Rust's `u32` is always exactly 32 bits. Even on Arduino (8-bit register size), `i128` exist as groupings of  smaller registers.

Comment: @Shepmaster: It's easy to compose an integer out of 8-bits blocks, but when your blocks are 9 or 10 bits, then what do you do? From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char there appears to be 24-bits DSP for example, the same also mentions that POSIX requires 8-bits bytes so a lot of system should be okay.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I understand that there are such platforms, and that *C* may or may not handle them, but does *Rust* actually attempt to work for any of these types of platforms?

Comment: @Shepmaster: *Rust All The Platforms!*.