# How to convert a u32 array to a u8 array in place?

Tags: rust

I want to convert a `[u32; 4]` to a `[u8; 16]` in place.

I know it is possible to use bitwise operation to get the 16 `u8` from the 4 `u32`. But I want to convert the array in place. How to do this using safe Rust or unsafe Rust?

```rust
let buffer: [u32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let hash: [u8; 16]; // how to convert from buffer to hash?
```

background information: I am calculating a 128-bit hash value, where the `[u32; 4]` is a buffer holding 4 `u32`.
And I want to convert the array to a `[u8; 16]`, as the final hash.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. I think the best solution is using the `align_to()` method of slices, which will give you a slice rather than an array. I'll look up the duplicates.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Why is `align_to()` better than `transmute()` in this case?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Because you at least can't get the alignment wrong, which is possible with `transmute()`. I know that `u8` has an alignment of 1, but in general it's preferable to use solutions where fewer things can go wrong. Of course the downside is that you don't get an array but a slice.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Given that `transmute()` is sound, and `align_to()` complicates the code considerably I feel like with a proper safety comment this is fine.

Comment: Fair enough. This always depends on context, e.g. who is working on this codebase? May the code be used in different context in the future? Will it likely be altered to work on different types? I'm generally much more reluctant to _recommend_ `transmute()` on StackOverflow than to _use_ it myself, because people will use the same answers in different contexts, where it may not be appropriate.

Comment: Related questions (possibly duplicates): [Convert array (or vector) of u16 (or u32, u64) to array of u8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631010/convert-array-or-vector-of-u16-or-u32-u64-to-array-of-u8) • [Converting a Vec<u32> to Vec<u8> in-place and with minimal overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690459/converting-a-vecu32-to-vecu8-in-place-and-with-minimal-overhead) • [Converting large number stored in array of u32 to bytes and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158788/converting-large-number-stored-in-array-of-u32-to-bytes-and-back)

Comment: [Similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697768/transmute-struct-into-array-in-rust/70699596#70699596=). Wanting to do something in place with data that fits into a register probably isn't very meaningful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be tempted to do a transmute, but I would advise against it, mainly because of the endianness, that is the final output would depend on wether your machine is big-endian or little-endian:

```
pub fn convert(data: &[u32; 4]) -> [u8; 16] {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(*data) }
}
```

Instead I'd just do it the boring way [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1eb8eb36fdd5222207bfc77b38edf6b3):

```
pub fn convert(data: &[u32; 4]) -> [u8; 16] {
    let mut res = [0; 16];
    for i in 0..4 {
        res[4*i..][..4].copy_from_slice(&data[i].to_le_bytes());
    }
    res
}
```

Change `to_le_bytes()` to `to_be_bytes()` if you need big-endian instead. Or use `to_ne_bytes()` to get native endianness if you don't care about that.

If you are worried about performance (but why should you be?) the generated code for `x86_64` using native endianness is as good as it gets:

```
playground::convert:
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movups  (%rsi), %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
    retq
```

Comment: As long as the hash is not persisted, endianness is not a problem.

Comment: A little bit, without all index calculations (and compiles to the same code): `for (&data, res) in std::iter::zip(data, res.chunks_mut(4)) { res.copy_from_slice(&data.to_le_bytes()); }`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Sure. But if it for internal use only, I'd say that the OP could use the `[u32; 4]` directly.

Comment: Also a neat trick is to replace `res[4*i..4*(i+1)]` with `res[4*i..][..4]`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: `res[4*i..][..4]`, that is a nice trick! I'll write that from now on. And with your permission I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: You can add that happily. It's not mine, however, and I don't really remember where I saw it first.

Answer (score 1):

Slighly simpler/more idiomatic take on the currently accepted answer:

```rust
pub fn convert(source: &[u32; 4]) -> [u8; 16] {
    let mut dest = [0; 16];
    for (dest_c, source_e) in dest.chunks_exact_mut(4).zip(source.iter()) {
        dest_c.copy_from_slice(&source_e.to_le_bytes())
    }
    dest
}
```

Based on the disassemly, it seems to generate simpler ASM, probably because of stronger assumptions  due to iterations entirely based on iterators (I've checked on a array with 64k u32 entries, but I haven't analyzed the ASM thoroughly).

Comment: This is not "in place" as requested in the question. The original source is borrowed, and the result is a new value with separate storage.

Comment: As I wrote, this is a slighly more iditiomatic take of the (part 2 of the) accepted answer. If you think this should be integrated in the current answer (as update), it makes sense - feel free it suggest it, and I'll delete this after it's integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `unsafe`, it is possible easily with [`transmute()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html):

```rust
pub fn convert(v: [u32; 4]) -> [u8; 16] {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(v) }
}
```

I don't think there is an efficient safe way without external crates. If you can adopt extern crates, you can use [`bytemuck::cast()`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/fn.cast.html):

```rust
pub fn convert(v: [u32; 4]) -> [u8; 16] {
    bytemuck::cast(v)
}
```

Comment: There is an efficient safe way if you just trust the optimizer.

Comment: @Caesar I would not use `transmute()` for that indeed, but `bytemuch` is a good option, and better than a loop (if you don't care about endianness).