# String literal with an escape sequence followed by a digit

Tags: c++, escaping, string-literals

I need to represent an arbitrary sequence of bytes as a C++ string literal, but in the typical case where it is mostly an ASCII string, keep it as readable as reasonably possible. The obvious way to do this is as a string literal with escape sequences where necessary, but this runs into a problem.

Consider `"\xaaa"`. The `\x` escape sequence can take at most two hexadecimal digits. I would therefore expect the compiler to take those two hexadecimal digits, consider the escape sequence to be complete, and go back to reading literal characters. Instead, Microsoft C++ says `error C2022: '2730': too big for character`.

The same problem happens with octal e.g. `"\5555"`.

As far as I can see, perhaps the least awkward solution is to stop and restart the string literal, e.g. `"\xaa" "a"`.

Is there a more compact/idiomatic solution?

Comment: *"The `\x` escape sequence can take at most two hexadecimal digits."* -- not true. According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape#Notes): "Hexadecimal escape sequences have no length limit and terminate at the first character that is not a valid hexadecimal digit."

Comment: @JaMiT Right, fair correction; I should have said, can *usefully* take at most two.

Comment: *"Is there a more compact/idiomatic solution?"* -- well, you could remove the space between the literals, but I don't see how you could hope to make it more compact than adding only two characters (and FWIW, this approach is mentioned in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes)). But maybe someone can. Never say never.

Comment: @nwallace - The language has no upper limit on the size of the literal, as it has no upper limit on the size of a `char`. Two hex digits fits the *lower* limit.

Comment: @rwallace -- re: "can **usefully* take at most 2" -- that's true for system where `char` is 8 bits. C and C++ are not restricted to such systems, and there are systems that have [larger `char` types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char).