# In computers 32-bit or 64-bit processors are used, why not 40-bit or other numbers?

Tags: cpu-architecture, 32bit-64bit, word-size

For example, in case of 32-bit processors, a word is 4-byte long. Is it also possible to use 5-byte word or others?

Comment: 32 and 64 are powers a 2.  32 = 2^5 64 = 2 ^ 6.  The 'next bittage' will probably be 128 (2 ^ 7).

Comment: yeah but why that is necessary, in depth there are 1's and 0's.

Comment: It is not strictly necessary. But there are several reasons. Apart from 32=100000b and 64=1000000b being "nice" numbers in binary, the powers of 2 have many divisors (that are, of course, again powers of 2). Going even deeper here would lead to details about the design of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit and memory/cache hierarchies that are probably beyond the scope of an answer here (though one could nevertheless *try* to give a good answer - I won't dare to...)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29#The_power_of_two

Comment: Computer designers like powers of 2, it makes the binary circuit design much simpler.  5 is not a happy number.  Not to burst your bubble, but the most popular 64-bit processor actually uses 40 bits for the address bus :)

Comment: @npostavs, I have seen the link, but the crux line is confusing :P, "Converting the index of an item in an array into the address of the item then requires only a shift operation rather than a multiplication."

Comment: To convert an index to an array offset you need to do `index * sizeof(item)`, if `sizeof(item)` is a power of 2 you can use left shift instead of multiply. The wikipedia page also has examples of non-power-of-2 word-size chips.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it also possible to use 5-byte word or others

If you're talking about whether it's possible for a *hardware architecture* to have 5-byte word then obviously yes, the **word size can be anything** that the designer wants and it's entirely possible to have a platform with 55-bit word and 11-bit byte. It's just that powers of 2 are common nowadays, but in the pass [other word sizes exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes). There were 40-bit platforms with 5-bit byte or 60-bit architectures with 6-bit char for example. See also

- [Why is number of bits always(?) a power of two?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1606827/995714)
- [Have there been any instruction sets with an odd register width?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22126/1981)
- [Exotic architectures the standards committees care about](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6971886/995714)
- [System where 1 byte != 8 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5516044/995714)

---

If you mean *using a 40-bit type in a platform with 32-bit word* then the answer is still yes. You can even use just a few bits instead of the whole byte/word through [bit fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). Technically compilers can support **any integer sizes** on any architectures, like a 12-bit, 30-bit or 96-bit int on a 16-bit computer. In fact Clang has just got a new extension for integers with arbitrary bit width called [`_ExtInt`](http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html) and that's going to be standardized as [`_BitInt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) in C23. See also

- [If a 32-bit integer overflows, can we use a 40-bit structure instead of a 64-bit long one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27705409/995714)
- [Which C datatype can represent a 40-bit binary number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9595225/995714)

> why not 40-bit or other numbers?

Performance would suffer **a lot**. We need ***more instructions*** to deal with non-native integer sizes. If the size is smaller than a word then compilers need to emit bitwise instructions to mask out the remaining bits. In the reverse case we need multiple instructions to work on multiple words

Another important thing is [***misalignment***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). Modern CPUs work more efficiently when a variable's address is a multiple of its size, or at least a multiple of the data bus width/word size. Working with an odd-sized variable is just awkward

---

That said, **there exist many 32-bit architectures with a 40-bit type**, like the [TI C6000](http://www.ti.com/processors/digital-signal-processors/c6000-floating-point-dsp/overview.html) or the [TI C5500](http://www.ti.com/processors/digital-signal-processors/c5000-low-power-dsp/overview.html) DSPs

> `long` is
>
> - **40 bits** or 5 bytes for C6000 COFF
>
> [...] and C5500 has **40-bit `long long`**
>
> [*C89 Support in TI Compilers*](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/C89_Support_in_TI_Compilers)

It's because those DSPs have a special 40-bit accumulator to allow adding 32-bit numbers 256 times without overflow. But why don't just use a 64-bit accumulator? That'll need a much bigger ALU, require more power and run slower (because bigger area means longer distance between hardware components, and operating on big numbers are slower than on smaller ones) which is unacceptable in a DSP which is designed for performance (and possibly also power)

> ... For instance, the Texas Instruments TMS320C6000, a DSP processor, uses 32 bits to represent the type `int` and 40 bits to represent the type `long` (this choice is not uncommon). Those processors (usually DSP) that use 24 bits to represent the type `int`, often use 48 bits to represent the type `long`. The use of 24/48 bit integer type representations can be driven by application requirements where a 32/64-bit integer type representation are not cost effective.
>
> [*The New C Standard (Excerpted material): An Economic and Cultural Commentary*](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.2.4.2.1.pdf)

In fact, 40-bit int is very common among DSPs (other examples being [Blackfin](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/software-manuals/cces-blackfincompiler-library-manual.pdf) and [SHARC](https://www.analog.com/en/products/landing-pages/001/sharc-processor-architectural-overview.html#)). SHARC even has an 80-bit accumulator so you can add a lot of 64-bit values without worrying about overflow

---

But you don't need a special architecture or special compiler support for that. You can still use a 40-bit variable if you **really need to**, for example when you work with a huge array where 64-bit integers would make it too large to fit in main memory and fewer items would fit in the cache. The simplest way to do that is to disable alignment with `#pragma pack` or `__attribute__((packed))`

```c
struct int40_t {
    int64_t : 40;
} __attribute__((packed));
int40_t myArray[200] __attribute__((packed));
```

or access the values from a simple char array (based on [cmm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27713173/995714))

```c
unsigned char _5byteInts[5*size+3];  // +3 avoids overfetch of last element

int64_t get5byteInt(size_t index)
{
    int64_t v = 0;
    memcpy(&v, &_5byteInts[index*5], 5);        // little endian
    return (v << 24) >> 24;
}

void set5byteInt(size_t index, int64_t value)
{
    memcpy(&_5byteInts[index*5], &value, 5);    // little endian
}
```

But those will result in bad performance on architectures without unaligned access. You can pack four 40-bit ints to a single 20-byte struct to have better alignment

```c
struct four_int40s {
    uint32_t low[4];
    uint8_t hi[4];
};
```

Comment: The question is asking about sizes the HW natively supports.  10-byte x87 FP would be an example, but not software implementation of 40-bit integers on an ISA like x86 with 32 and 64-bit native operand sizes.  i.e. it's asking why there aren't 40-bit *machines*, not C types.  On such a machine, an array of 40-bit words could all be naturally-aligned, assuming CHAR_BIT=10 or (less likely) that alignment worked in multiples of 5 octets (the word size).  Or that CHAR_BIT=40 and it's only word-addressable.

Comment: Or better to ask it this way. Why not defining a byte as 10-bits instead of 8-bits and always use a 40-bit architecture instead of maintaining two systems of 32 and 64 bits. 32-bit has limit and 64-bit is a waste. 40-bit is a reasonable size. Photographers also love 10-bit color depth. By 20-bits you can also show all required unicode characters. 16, 32 are very bad numbers for human needs. In addition, 1024 can be understood by human better than 256. And it is also closer to the concept of Kilo, Mega, Giga.

Comment: @barej Unicode is 21-bit, not 20-bit, [the last code point is U+10FFFF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351/995714). And better for human doesn't scale up well in computers

Answer (score 0):

Historically, there have been a few computers with word sizes not a power of two, as in this [Table of word sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)). However, eventually people discovered that address arithmetic is much easier to implement when the address size is a power of two.

Consider an operation such as "jump forward by 14 words". If word size is a power of two, say 64, then the circuit needs to shift the number 14 by `log(64)/log(2)=6` and add to `ip`, and that can easily be done in 1 cycle. If, however, the word size is 36, as in IBM 701, then the number 14 would have to be multiplied by 36, and that would take more cycles. Given that multiplying an integer by word size is a very common operation the slowdown would be significant.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not clear. Suppose I have addresses in 4-bit and a word is of 4-bit length. I want to jump 2 words, `2<<log(4)/log(2)=8` equivalently it is `1000` that would be added in `ip`. My addresses are such that:  `0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 ...`  jumping two words from  `0000` should land on `0011` but according to the formula it is `1000`?

Comment: @rneha725, you are right, I was thinking in bits instead of bytes. If your addressing is in 8-bit bytes, as in most computers today, you've got to divide word size by byte size.

Comment: 40-bit words would be plausible with 10-bit bytes, for example.  Or only word-addressable.  Yes, as you say, the word-size should be a power-of-2 times the byte size.